# How to access token to modify youtube videos annotations with programmatically

Tags: video, youtube, annotations, youtube-api

I am using javascript to update videos annotations in youtube, and to accomplish this I need to get the access token for each video in my channel.
there is any way to get it with php API or javascript?

Below the code that i use to update annotations:

```
        var data = getXml();
    data = data.replace(/<requestHeader(.*?)video_id=".*?"(.*?)>/, '<requestHeader$1video_id="'+id+'"$2>');
    data = data.replace(/<authenticationHeader(.*?)auth_token=".*?"(.*?)>/, '<authenticationHeader$1auth_token="'+auth_token+'"$2>');       
    console.log(data);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://www.youtube.com/annotations_auth/update2', true);
    xhr.send(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JS example of OAuth2. You can also find other JavaScript examples in the same directory.

"https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/javascript/auth.js"